# mpi4py performance discrepancy after profiling

Tags: python-3.x, profiling, mpi, mpi4py, cprofile

I have been doing some work with MPI4py arrays, and I recently came across the performance increase after using `Scatterv()` functions. I have developed a code to inspect the data type of an input object and, in case it is a numeric numpy array, it performs the scattering with `Scatterv()`, otherwise it does so with a proper-implemented function.

The code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
import cProfile
from line_profiler import LineProfiler

def ScatterV(object, comm, root = 0):
    optimize_scatter, object_type = np.zeros(1), None

    if rank == root:
        if isinstance(object, np.ndarray):
            if object.dtype in [np.float64, np.float32, np.float16, np.float,
                                np.int, np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64]:
                optimize_scatter = 1
                object_type = object.dtype

            else: optimize_scatter, object_type = 0, None
        else: optimize_scatter, object_type = 0, None

        optimize_scatter = np.array(optimize_scatter, dtype=np.float64).ravel()

    comm.Bcast([optimize_scatter, 1, MPI.DOUBLE], root=root)
    object_type = comm.bcast(object_type, root=root)

    if int(optimize_scatter) == 1:

        if rank == root:

            displs = [int(i)*object.shape[1] for i in
                          np.linspace(0, object.shape[0], comm.size + 1)]
            counts = [displs[i+1] - displs[i] for i in range(len(displs)-1)]
            lens = [int((displs[i+1] - displs[i])/(object.shape[1]))
                        for i in range(len(displs)-1)]
            displs = displs[:-1]
            shape = object.shape

            object = object.ravel().astype(np.float64, copy=False)

        else:
            object, counts, displs, shape, lens = None, None, None, None, None

        counts = comm.bcast(counts, root=root)
        displs = comm.bcast(displs, root=root)
        lens = comm.bcast(lens, root=root)
        shape = list(comm.bcast(shape, root=root))

        shape[0] = lens[rank]
        shape = tuple(shape)

        x = np.zeros(counts[rank])

        comm.Scatterv([object, counts, displs, MPI.DOUBLE], x, root=root)


        return  np.reshape(x, (-1,) + shape[1:]).astype(object_type, copy=False)

    else:
        return comm.scatter(object, root=root)


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size, rank = comm.Get_size(), comm.Get_rank()



if rank == 0:
    arra = (np.random.rand(10000000, 10) * 100).astype(np.float64, copy=False)
else: arra = None

lp = LineProfiler()

lp_wrapper = lp(ScatterV)
lp_wrapper(arra, comm)

if rank == 4: lp.print_stats()


pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

f2 = ScatterV(arra, comm)

pr.disable()

if rank == 4: pr.print_stats()
```

The analysis with `LineProfiler` yields the following results [cut to show conflictive lines only]:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 2.05001 s
File: /media/SETH_DATA/SETH_Alex/BigMPI4py/prueba.py
Function: ScatterV at line 26

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   ...                                          
    41         1    1708453.0 1708453.0     83.3      comm.Bcast([optimize_scatter, 1, MPI.DOUBLE], root=root)
    42         1        148.0    148.0      0.0      object_type = comm.bcast(object_type, root=root)
   ...                                
    76         1        264.0    264.0      0.0          counts = comm.bcast(counts, root=root)
    77         1         16.0     16.0      0.0          displs = comm.bcast(displs, root=root)
    78         1         14.0     14.0      0.0          lens = comm.bcast(lens, root=root)
    79         1          9.0      9.0      0.0          shape = list(comm.bcast(shape, root=root))
 ...                                
    86         1     340971.0 340971.0     16.6          comm.Scatterv([object, counts, displs, MPI.DOUBLE], x, root=root)
```

The analysis with `cProfile` yields the following results:

```
         17 function calls in 0.462 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.127    0.127    0.127    0.127 {method 'Bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
        1    0.335    0.335    0.335    0.335 {method 'Scatterv' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
```

In both cases, the `Bcast` method consumes a lot of time in comparison with `ScatterV` method. Even more, with `LinePprofiler`, the `Bcast` method is 5 times slower than `ScatterV` method, which seems completely incoherent to me since `Bcast` is only broadcasting an array of 10 elements.

If I swap the lines 41 and 42, these are the results:

`LineProfiler`

```
41         1    1666718.0 1666718.0     83.0      object_type = comm.bcast(object_type, root=root)
42         1         47.0     47.0      0.0      comm.Bcast([optimize_scatter, 1, MPI.DOUBLE], root=root)
87         1     341728.0 341728.0     17.0          comm.Scatterv([object, counts, displs, MPI.DOUBLE], x, root=root)
```

`cProfile`

```
1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'Bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
1    0.339    0.339    0.339    0.339 {method 'Scatterv' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
5    0.129    0.026    0.129    0.026 {method 'bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
```

If I vary the size of the array to be scattered, the time consumption of `ScatterV` and `Bcast` also vary, at the same rate. For instance, if I increase the size 10 times (100000000), the results are:

`LineProfiler`

```
41         1   16304301.0 16304301.0     82.8      comm.Bcast([optimize_scatter, 1, MPI.DOUBLE], root=root)
42         1        235.0    235.0      0.0      object_type = comm.bcast(object_type, root=root)
87         1    3393658.0 3393658.0     17.2          comm.Scatterv([object, counts, displs, MPI.DOUBLE], x, root=root)
```

`cProfile`

```
 1    1.348    1.348    1.348    1.348 {method 'Bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
    1    4.517    4.517    4.517    4.517 {method 'Scatterv' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
    5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
```

If instead of selecting the results for rank 4, I select them for any rank > 1, the same result happens. However, for rank = 0 the results differ:

`LineProfiler`

```
41         1        186.0    186.0      0.0      comm.Bcast([optimize_scatter, 1, MPI.DOUBLE], root=root)
42         1        244.0    244.0      0.0      object_type = comm.bcast(object_type, root=root)
87         1    4722349.0 4722349.0    100.0          comm.Scatterv([object, counts, displs, MPI.DOUBLE], x, root=root)
```

`cProfile`

```
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'Bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
    1    5.921    5.921    5.921    5.921 {method 'Scatterv' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
    5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'bcast' of 'mpi4py.MPI.Comm' objects}
```

In this case, the `Bcast` method has a similar computation time as the rest of `bcast` methods.

I have also tried to, instead of using `Bcast`on line 41, using `bcast` and `scatter`, which yield the same results.

Given that, I think that the increased time consumption is attributed erroneously only to the first broadcast, which means that both profilers yield false timings for parallelization processes.

I am quite sure that the internal structure of profilers is not done to work with parallelizable functions, but I post this question to know if someone has experienced similar results.

Comment: Keep in mind the profiler reports the time spent sendin/receiving the message **plus** the time non root ranks wait for the message (synchronization so to speak). If you have a lot of imbalance, some tasks might spend a lot of time waiting in the broadcast. Then they are kind of synchronized for the scatterv, so the profiler report it as faster). For timing purpose, you can add a `MPI_Barrier()` before the broadcast. I guess most of the time will be spent in the barrier (no, the barrier is not slow, you are mainly measuring imbalance), and scatterv() will be slower than bcast().

Answer (score 0):

In response to Gilles Gouaillardet, I have included `comm.Barrier()` to the lines before and after each `bcast` call, and most of the signal is summed up in these `comm.Barrier()` calls.

Here is an example with `LineProfiler`.

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 2.17248 s
File: /media/SETH_DATA/SETH_Alex/BigMPI4py/prueba.py
Function: ScatterV at line 26

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    26                                           def ScatterV(object, comm, root = 0):
    27         1          7.0      7.0      0.0      optimize_scatter, object_type = np.zeros(1), None
    28                                           
    29         1          2.0      2.0      0.0      if rank == root:
    30                                                   if isinstance(object, np.ndarray):
    31                                                       if object.dtype in [np.float64, np.float32, np.float16, np.float,
    32                                                                           np.int, np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64]:
    33                                                           optimize_scatter = 1
    34                                                           object_type = object.dtype
    35                                           
    36                                                       else: optimize_scatter, object_type = 0, None
    37                                                   else: optimize_scatter, object_type = 0, None
    38                                           
    39                                                   optimize_scatter = np.array(optimize_scatter, dtype=np.float64).ravel()
    40                                           
    41         1    1677662.0 1677662.0     77.2      comm.Barrier()
    42         1         76.0     76.0      0.0      comm.Bcast([optimize_scatter, 1, MPI.DOUBLE], root=root)
    43         1        345.0    345.0      0.0      comm.Barrier()
    44         1        111.0    111.0      0.0      object_type = comm.bcast(object_type, root=root)
    45         1        166.0    166.0      0.0      comm.Barrier()
    46                                           
    47                                           
    48                                           
    49         1          7.0      7.0      0.0      if int(optimize_scatter) == 1:
    50                                           
    51         1          2.0      2.0      0.0          if rank == root:
    52                                                       if object.ndim > 1:
    53                                                           displs = [int(i)*object.shape[1] for i in
    54                                                                     np.linspace(0, object.shape[0], comm.size + 1)]
    55                                                       else:
    56                                                           displs = [int(i) for i in np.linspace(0, object.shape[0], comm.size + 1)]
    57                                           
    58                                                       counts = [displs[i+1] - displs[i] for i in range(len(displs)-1)]
    59                                           
    60                                                       if object.ndim > 1:
    61                                                           lens = [int((displs[i+1] - displs[i])/(object.shape[1]))
    62                                                                   for i in range(len(displs)-1)]
    63                                                       else:
    64                                                           lens = [displs[i+1] - displs[i] for i in range(len(displs)-1)]
    65                                           
    66                                                       displs = displs[:-1]
    67                                           
    68                                           
    69                                                       shape = object.shape
    70                                           
    71                                           
    72                                           
    73                                                       if object.ndim > 1:
    74                                                           object = object.ravel().astype(np.float64, copy=False)
    75                                           
    76                                           
    77                                                   else:
    78         1          2.0      2.0      0.0              object, counts, displs, shape, lens = None, None, None, None, None
    79                                           
    80         1        295.0    295.0      0.0          counts = comm.bcast(counts, root=root)
    81         1         66.0     66.0      0.0          displs = comm.bcast(displs, root=root)
    82         1          6.0      6.0      0.0          lens = comm.bcast(lens, root=root)
    83         1          9.0      9.0      0.0          shape = list(comm.bcast(shape, root=root))
    84                                           
    85         1          2.0      2.0      0.0          shape[0] = lens[rank]
    86         1          3.0      3.0      0.0          shape = tuple(shape)
    87                                           
    88         1         33.0     33.0      0.0          x = np.zeros(counts[rank])
    89                                           
    90         1         76.0     76.0      0.0          comm.Barrier()
    91         1     351187.0 351187.0     16.2          comm.Scatterv([object, counts, displs, MPI.DOUBLE], x, root=root)
    92         1     142352.0 142352.0      6.6          comm.Barrier()
    93                                           
    94         1          5.0      5.0      0.0          if len(shape) > 1:
    95         1         66.0     66.0      0.0              return  np.reshape(x, (-1,) + shape[1:]).astype(object_type, copy=False)
    96                                                   else:
    97                                                       return x.view(object_type)
    98                                           
    99                                           
   100                                               else:
   101                                                   return comm.scatter(object, root=root)
```

The 77.2% of time is spent on the first `comm.Barrier()` element, so I can safely assume that neither `bcast` call is taking such an overwhelming amount of time. I will consider adding `comm.Barrier()`calls for future profilings.

Comment: keep in mind adding a barrier() has an impact on your application behavior (worst case scenario is causing a deadlock) so you should at least double check the elapsed time is about the same with and without the barrier and profiler.